# How to replace double spaces with one space in filenames (also subdirectories) (CloudLinux Server release 6.10)

Tags: linux, replace, rename, spaces

I want to replace double spaces with one space in the filenames of a lot of photos. These photos are located in directory /foto and it's subfolders. How to do this? For example "photo   1.jpg" needs to become "photo 1.jpg"

The best way is to use commandline, because it's on CloudLinux server. (and it is over 50GB of photos). I searched here on Stackoverflow, also Google to find the command I need. I guess rename is the one to use, or mv.

The only things I found were commands about replacing space and replacing other symbols, but not about double (multiple) spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -iname \*.* | rename -v "s/\s{2}/ /g"
```

This is the final command which helped me out. I used perl rename, see answer by Gilles

Answer (score 0):

Use this, using Perl's rename :

```
rename 's/\s{2}/ /g' files*
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl rename` executable.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: If you use Linux, ensure you have the perl's rename  with `file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))` and remove -n switch if you want to do it for real

Comment: It gave ELF so I will install perl one =)

Comment: There a link for a standalone script, but can be installed via package manager : `rename` or `prename`

Comment: Gilles, check my post, I added the output of SSH. Very weird....doesn't run Perl rename, but I updated the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191263/discussion-between-gilles-quenot-and-gijsve).